# Summing dates across multiple rows in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

We have a Table that stores alarms for certain SetPoints in our system. I'm attempting to write a query that first gets the difference between two dates (spread across two rows), and then sums all of the date differences to get a total sum for the amount of time the setpoint was in alarm.

We have one database where I've accomplished similar, but in that case, both the startTime and endTime were in the same row. In this case, this is not adequate

Some example Data

```
|   Row   |   TagID   |   SetPointID   |         EventLogTime         |   InAlarm   |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    1    |     1     |        2       |    2016-01-01 01:49:18.070   |      1      |
|    2    |     1     |        1       |    2016-01-01 03:23:39.970   |      1      |
|    3    |     1     |        2       |    2016-01-01 03:23:40.070   |      0      |
|    4    |     1     |        1       |    2016-01-01 08:04:01.260   |      0      |
|    5    |     1     |        2       |    2016-01-01 08:04:01.370   |      1      |
|    6    |     1     |        1       |    2016-01-01 11:40:36.367   |      1      |
|    7    |     1     |        2       |    2016-01-01 11:40:36.503   |      0      |
|    8    |     1     |        1       |    2016-01-01 13:00:30.263   |      0      |
```

Results

```
|   TagID    |   SetPointID   |   TotalTimeInAlarm   |
------------------------------------------------------
|     1      |        1       |    6.004443  (hours) |
|     1      |        2       |    5.182499  (hours) |
```

Essentially, what I need to do is to get the start time and end time for each tag and each setpoint, then I need to get the total time in alarm. I'm thing CTEs might be able to help, but I'm not sure.

I believe the pseudo query logic would be similar to

```
Define @startTime DATETIME, @endTime DATETIME

SELECT TagID,
       SetPointID,
       ABS(First Occurrence of InAlarm = True (since last occurrence WHERE InAlarm = False) 
           - First Occurrence of InAlarm = False (since last occurrence WHERE InAlarm = True)) 
       -- IF no InAlarm = False use @endTime.
GROUP BY TagID, SetPointID
```

Comment: what should the output look like?

Comment: Essentially, in the end, it would just be: `TagID | SetPointID | TotalTimeInAlarm`

Comment: @Jdsfighter put sample result into your question. With result values corresponding your sample data.

Comment: How did you come up with the desired output? What defines being out of alarm? For set point 1 your enter alarm at 3:23:39.970 and the next entry is not until 8:04:01.260. The different there is a lot more than.19 hours.

Comment: @IvanStarostin I have updated it with output data.

Comment: Well now the input and output example has changed but the logic of the time still doesn't make any sense to me..

Comment: could you please elaborate how did you end up with 0.2501851 for point 1? Just write the formula, please, like this time plus that time minus that time etc.

Comment: I apologize, I was doing a `DateDiff(ss, start,end) / 86400.0` whereas is should have been dividing by 3600.0.

Comment: So what is the correct formula here? select DateDiff(ss, '2016-01-01 03:23:39.970', '2016-01-01 08:04:01.260') / 3600.0 returns 4.672777 which is nothing like 6.004443 This really shouldn't be this difficult.

Comment: @Jdsfighter: would it be hard for you to write something like "take time from row 1, add time from row 2, subtract time from row 3" etc?

Comment: @SeanLange  thats because you didnt add the next "InAlarm" sum  .. `SELECT DateDiff(ss, '2016-01-01 03:23:39.970', '2016-01-01 08:04:01.260') / 3600.0 + DateDiff(ss, '2016-01-01 11:40:36.367', '2016-01-01 13:00:30.263') / 3600.0
`

Comment: @Quassnoi `([Row 4] - [Row2]) + ([Row 8] - [Row 6])` This is Row 1 in the results. `([Row 3] - [Row1]) + ([Row 7] - [Row 5])` This is row 2 in the results.

Comment: @JamieD77 yeah I just figured that part out. Man this would so much easier with an explanation instead of trying to extract the rules like this.

Comment: Next question. What version of sql server are you using? The answer will very greatly if you are on 2012+

Comment: @Jdsfighter: that's the spirit! Now, what happens if  you start with `inAlarm = 0`? what happens if there are two or more consecutive records with `inAlarm = 1`? what happens if the series end with `inAlarm = 1`?

Comment: It should almost never happen, but we only care about when it first goes in alarm and when it's first cleared

Comment: I'm on 2012 and 2014 (multiple client databases)

Comment: You'd want to join the table with alarm=1 using an `on` clause on itself that finds the closest next alarm=0 for a matching id and setpoint

Comment: @Jdsfighter: so if there's only one record with alarm = 1, we don't record any time at all, right?

Comment: @Quassnoi correct, if it doesn't get cleared, I think the solution would be to subtract the end time

Comment: @Jdsfighter: subtract from what?

Comment: @Quassnoi Again, I apologize, I was running errands and typing a lot of this out over mobile. In my query, I have a start time and end time variable. By modifying Tom's answer below to honor my start and end time variables, I was able to coalesce the EndingEventLogTime to be my end time variable in the event that it was null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `LEAD` windowed function (or `LAG`) to do this pretty easily. This assumes that the rows always come in pairs with 1-0-1-0 for "InAlarm". If that doesn't happen then it's going to throw things off. You would need to have business rules for these situations in any event.

```
;WITH CTE_Timespans AS
(
    SELECT
        TagID,
        SetPointID,
        InAlarm,
        EventLogTime,
        LEAD(EventLogTime, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY TagID, SetPointID ORDER BY EventLogTime) AS EndingEventLogTime
    FROM
        My_Table
)
SELECT
    TagID,
    SetPointID,
    SUM(DATEDIFF(SS, EventLogTime, EndingEventLogTime))/3600.0 AS TotalTime
FROM
    CTE_Timespans
WHERE
    InAlarm = 1
GROUP BY
    TagID,
    SetPointID
```

Comment: With a minor modification by adding a set @endDate variable and coalescing `EndingEventLogTime` if null to the value of @endDate, this seems to work properly. What is the purpose of putting `InAlarm` in the where clause? Is it simply to filter any rows that were not still alarming?

Comment: You want to only sum up those time spans that started with a 1. The CTE will actually return all rows (including those with 0 values for InAlarm) along with the time from the next row. You want to make sure that you're not adding in those time spans that started with a 0.

Comment: BTW, you could also add in a `LEAD` for the `InAlarm` value and filter on only rows that have a start of 1 and end value of 0 for `InAlarm`.

Answer (score 2):

One easy way is to use OUTER APPLY to get the next date that is not InAlarm

```
SELECT  mt.TagID,
        mt.SetPointID,
        SUM(DATEDIFF(ss,mt.EventLogTime,oa.EventLogTime)) / 3600.0 AS [TotalTimeInAlarm]
FROM    MyTable mt
        OUTER APPLY (SELECT MIN([EventLogTime]) EventLogTime
                     FROM   MyTable mt2
                     WHERE  mt.TagID = mt2.TagID
                            AND mt.SetPointID = mt2.SetPointID
                            AND mt2.EventLogTime > mt.EventLogTime
                            AND InAlarm = 0
                    ) oa
WHERE   mt.InAlarm = 1
GROUP BY mt.TagID,
        mt.SetPointID
```

`LEAD()` might perform better if using MSSQL 2012+

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server 2014+:

```
SELECT  tagId, setPointId, SUM(DATEDIFF(second, pt, eventLogTime)) / 3600. AS diff
FROM    (
        SELECT  *,
                LAG(inAlarm) OVER (PARTITION BY tagId, setPointId ORDER BY eventLogTime, row) ppa,
                LAG(eventLogTime) OVER (PARTITION BY tagId, setPointId ORDER BY eventLogTime, row) pt
        FROM    (
                SELECT  LAG(inAlarm) OVER (PARTITION BY tagId, setPointId ORDER BY eventLogTime, row) pa,
                        *
                FROM    mytable
                ) q
        WHERE   EXISTS
                (
                SELECT  pa
                EXCEPT
                SELECT  inAlarm
                )
        ) q
WHERE   ppa = 0
        AND inAlarm = 1
GROUP BY
        tagId, setPointId
```

This will filter out consecutive events with same alarm state